# How to use reflection to serialise and deserialise (generic way). Not using an dll

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to create a Class with a method where I can load a file (In this case CSV) and convert it to any predefined datastructure within my program.

With a lot of help from other articles I've written the following code, But I got stuck. (so the placed code has errors).

The idea is that I use the method CsvSerialise, the input is a byteArray and transform it to an object list where the input is what kind of output type I want.

If anyone has some Ideas, please give them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DocumentArchiveV2.Util
{
    public class CsvSerialiser
    {
        public List<Output> CsvSerialise<Output, DestinationFormat>(byte[] csvData, Type destinationType)
        {
            try
            {
                List<List<string>> lislistCsvData = BinaryDataToList(csvData);
                List<string> columnNames = lislistCsvData[0];
                List< destinationType >  = new List<DestinationFormat>();


                // loop over de regels / records
                for (int i = 1; i < lislistCsvData.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                    var Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(destinationType);
                    var properties = Instance.GetType().GetProperties();

                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        int index = columnNames.FindIndex(x => x == property.Name);
                        if (index >= 0)
                        {
                            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = destinationType.GetProperty(lislistCsvData[i][index]);
                            Type propertyType = propertyInfo.GetType();
                            var geconverteerdeWaarde = VindPropertyNaam(propertyType, lislistCsvData[i][index]);
                            propertyInfo.SetValue(propertyInfo, geconverteerdeWaarde);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public object VindPropertyNaam(Type type, string popertyName)
        {
            try
            {
                var parse = type.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
                if (parse == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
                return parse.Invoke(null, new object[] { popertyName });
            }
            //or don't catch
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


        private object LoadRecord(Type propertyType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private List<List<string>> BinaryDataToList(byte[] csvData)
        {
            try
            {
                List<List<string>> serialised = new List<List<string>>();

                foreach (var line in Regex.Split(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(csvData), "\r\n"))
                {
                    string[] splittedLine = line.Split(';');
                    serialised.Add(line.Split(';').ToList());
                }
                return serialised;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DiagnoseLib.Logging.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. That's code alright.

Comment: So what specifically is the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json is serializing objects from json strings and back. maybe you can borrow an idea or two from their source code

Comment: Hi,
The problem is that I cannot give a destination output. I need to declare a output list List<DestinationFormat> and add the values to this., The editor keeps giving errord.

Comment: Thanks FrankM, Ill take a look at that

Comment: Basic problems: **1.** You're looping through the data twice. **2.** You're reflecting the properties for each cell, which will be slow. Building an array for each column, with nulls for missing properties, will be faster. **3.** You're catching all exceptions and just rethrowing. **4.** Your CSV reader will break if you have a quoted string with a delimiter value `;` within. **Aside:** You say the editor is giving errors. We're not psychic, so you need to give us the full error messages and tell us where they occur if you want help.

Comment: With regard to #2 you can make it faster again, I believe, by using expression trees to create setters for each property, and then caching that for reuse each time you deserialize to that type. But that's for your own research.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much dislike your code due to numereous violations of OOP practicies known to be the best. However, since it is not the question you're asking, I'd like to ignore those and focus on what you'd like to get right now.

So basically what you're doing is called "parsing". It's all about taking a somehow formatted (CSV in your case) text and converting to internal data structures. Since yoy eager to come up with generic solution (which by itself is perfect thing to do, though as well much harder), you objectively don't know what kind of data structure it gonna be. Hence, you need be able to configure this process. How? Typically, with help of higer order functions. Something like `new DataStructureBuilder<TDataStructure>((environment, result) => result.Text = environemt["Text"])`. It is far from being a real code, however gives you an idea: there is a generic datastructure of (assuming) `TDataStructure` type and you specify the way it should be filled with data explicitly. `environment` stands for parsed text (that very moment, when you read the values you'd like you data strutctures to ship further, however yet those are stored into raw form of dictionaries, lists, hashsets, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I found where I went wrong.

I was trying to return a generic type while it should have been an objecttype

Thanks all who have given insight.

```
     public List<object> CsvSerialise(byte[] csvData, object destinationType)
            {
        // The rest of the code with some small adjustments
            }
```